# Avoid error when trying crawling the web

Tags: python, web-crawler, urllib

I am trying ' crawling the web in python '. the problem is that I get an error with the re module. Here is my code:

```
#Python27

import re
import urllib

htm = urllib.urlopen('http://www.4shared.com/')
wp = htm.read()
begin = []
for start_tag in wp:
    x = re.search('<a', wp)
    begin.append(x.end())
```

Here the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python Essen/Python27/crawling_web_pratice.py", line 23, in <module>
    a = re.search(start_tag, wp)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 146, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 251, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
error: nothing to repeat
```

Please How to avoid the error ?

Comment: You are using too low-level tools. Try to use special library like http://scrapy.org/
If you wish to do all the things manually, take a look at request lib - it makes working with url more comfortable and BeautifulSoup - for parsing html.

Comment: You're not showing the code that is causng the error, which is `a = re.search(start_tag, wp)`. I expect  the content of `start_tag` is not a valid regular expression.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your error. I suspect your file encoding. Can you make sure your python script file is encoded in UTF-8?

Comment: replace '<a' by r'\<a' ('<' matter)